# Confusing matrix manipulation in Lyapunov stability proof?

Tags: matrix-equations, lyapunov-functions

I was looking at the proof of the stability of a problem via the Lyapunov function in a paper. I don't think it is necessary to write the whole problem fully so I will focus just on the particular issue. Somewhere in the proof, they wrote that:
$$
\Theta^T*(\Psi^{T}\Gamma) *\Theta = \Theta^T*(\Gamma\Psi) *\Theta
$$

Where:
$\Theta$ is a $p \times n$ matrix of the parameter errors of the system (real matrix, time varying). $\Psi$ is a $p \times p$ matrix (real matrix, not time-varying). $\Gamma$ is a $p \times p$ symmetric positive definite matrix (real diagonal matrix, not time-varying).
The paper earlier defined a relationship between $\Psi$ and $\Gamma$ as:
$$
\Gamma * \Psi + \Psi^T*\Gamma > 0
$$
Which in my understanding means simply that $(\Gamma * \Psi)$ is positive definite.
So my question is how can we assert the first equation based only on the fact that $(\Gamma * \Psi)$ is positive definite? It seems to me, we must also assert that $(\Gamma * \Psi)$ is symmetric to be able to conclude that, no? The paper did not mention anything about $\Psi$ except it exists.

I appreciate the help. Thanks.
dd

P.S: Now that I think of it, perhaps the authors meant to say that: 
$$
Trace[\Theta^T*(\Psi^{T}\Gamma) *\Theta] = Trace[\Theta^T*(\Gamma\Psi) *\Theta]
$$
(which is obviously true if the 1st equation is correct, but the context of the problem was stability proof, so maybe it was a typo?) 
Still, it's not quite obvious to me how the two Trace expressions are equal.
NB: in my question, "*" represents ordinary everyday matrix multiplication. I apologise if any confusion,  I'm a new user 
here and still trying to get used to the commands for the proper math symbols. Thanks.

Comment: The $*$ is matrix multiplication as i see, the second inequality does not mean that the matrix $\Gamma \Psi$ is positive semi definite however if it is it will be hermitian (symmetric if real).

Comment: What is the meaning of "$\Psi$ is a constant matrix"? Is it a matrix such that all its entries are equal?

Comment: @Toni Mhax I understand that a real matrix A is positive definite if and only if $ A + A^T $ is positive definite. Since in general: $ (\Gamma*\Psi)^T = \Psi^T*\Gamma$, I assumed the inequality in the problem above could be interpreted that way. Is this not accurate?

Comment: @the_candyman: I'm no mathematician so I must apologize for abuse of expressions. By "constant" I meant the elements of the matrix are not changing in time, not that that all the elements are equal. I have edited my question to remove this kind of ambiguity. Thanks

Comment: @user623846  no it is not the definition of positive semi definite matrices

Comment: @ToniMhax, that's odd because this reference says that "This means that a real matrix A is positive definite iff the symmetric part is positive definite" http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PositiveDefiniteMatrix.html

Comment: Odd yes but they have a point. Anyway there is the definition where $A$  a complex matrix is positive semi definite if and only if $x^*Ax\ge 0$ for all $x$.  (It is  for hermitian matrices)

Comment: @ToniMhax, ok I appreciate the back and forth but it does not appear you are helping here or even shedding more light on my question. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Can you post the whole reference on, the paper i mean ?